# Is there any way where i can filter out words in python?

Tags: python, stop-words

Is there any way where i can filter out articles (the, a, an), pronouns, conjuntions (and, but), and other non topical words in python? Or is there a python package which can help?

I know I can use filter and stuff but that i would need a long list of all the words. Is there a package which contains these words already? I need to get rid of these words so that the memory consumed will be able to process the list with those words removed will be much lighter.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The term you are looking for is called **stop-word removal**.

A powerful library to accomplish this is [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)

It can handle a more sophisticated tokenization of your input text, easily allows to remove stop-words and much more:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning ... Arthur didn't feel very good."""
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

filtered_tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w.lower() in stopwords.words('english')]

print tokens
print filtered_tokens
```

This will print:

```
['At', 'eight', "o'clock", 'on', 'Thursday', 'morning', '...', 'Arthur', 'did', "n't", 'feel', 'very', 'good', '.']
['eight', "o'clock", 'Thursday', 'morning', '...', 'Arthur', "n't", 'feel', 'good', '.']
```